# How to use wget in PowerShell console with username and password

Tags: powershell, wget

I have seen couple of answers on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433151/powershell-a-positional-parameter-cannot-be-found-that-accepts-arguement-xxx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595554/what-is-the-correct-wget-command-syntax-for-https-with-username-and-password). But I always get some error similar to the following.

Not sure what am I doing wrong. I tried with the following variations, but all giving similar error. Please help.

```
wget --user "My.UserName@gmail.com" --password "MyWhatEver@pas$w0rd" https://bitbucket.org/WhatEver/WhatEverBranchName/get/master.zip
wget --user="My.UserName@gmail.com" --password="MyWhatEver@pas$w0rd" https://bitbucket.org/WhatEver/WhatEverBranchName/get/master.zip
wget --user='My.UserName@gmail.com' --password='MyWhatEver@pas$w0rd' https://bitbucket.org/WhatEver/WhatEverBranchName/get/master.zip
wget --user My.UserName@gmail.com --password MyWhatEver@pas$w0rd https://bitbucket.org/WhatEver/WhatEverBranchName/get/master.zip
```

```
Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'--password=MyWhatEver@pas$w0rd'.
At line:1 char:1
+ wget --user='My.UserName@gmail.com' --password='MyWhatEver@pas$w0rd'  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you actually want to run the program [`wget.exe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget), but PowerShell has a builtin alias `wget` for the cmdlet [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) that takes [precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22259706/1630171) over an executable, even if the executable is in the `PATH`. That cmdlet doesn't have parameters `--user` or `--password`, which is what causes the error you observed.

You can enforce running the executable by adding its extension, so PowerShell doesn't confuse it with the alias:

```
wget.exe --user 'My.UserName@gmail.com' --password 'MyWhatEver@pas$w0rd' https://bitbucket.org/WhatEver/WhatEverBranchName/get/master.zip
```

Note that you should put string literals with special characters like `$` in single quotes, otherwise PowerShell would expand something like `"MyWhatEver@pas$w0rd"` to `"MyWhatEver@pas"`, because the variable `$w0rd` is undefined.

If you want to use the cmdlet `Invoke-WebRequest` rather than the `wget` executable you need to provide credentials via a `PSCredential` object:

```
$uri  = 'https://bitbucket.org/WhatEver/WhatEverBranchName/get/master.zip'
$user = 'My.UserName@gmail.com'
$pass = 'MyWhatEver@pas$w0rd' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $pass)

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Credential $cred
```